HTML encoding in SQL Server msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail subject line
I am using SQL Server 2019; in my code I have HTML symbols. When I use the symbols for development in SQL Server Management Studio and for checking in the code in Visual Studio 2019 with Azure Devops as source code repository, things work as expected, but when I commit code into Azure Devops git repo, the HTML symbols (✅) are replaced with question marks (?).
Azure Devops:

How do I persist HTML symbols in the code, after using HTML encoding instead of the symbol makes body display work but subject line is still a problem please find code in question below.
SQL:
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
SET @subject = '>&#x2705;' + N' - my symbol'

DECLARE @body nvarchar(max)
SET @body = N'<font size=''2'' color=''red''>&#x2705;' + N' - my symbol</font>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'myemail@domain.com',
    @subject = @subject,
    @body = @body,
    @body_format = 'HTML';


I think as the parameter says that is for the body format, not the subject.  Dont think there is different parameter for subject, may not be able to with dbmail.

I really don't think Subject Lines can have HTML formatting.   Unicode Symbols may be allowed but may get marked down depending on the service.

Are you sure the symbols are being replaced, and not that it's just a display problem? Have you tried actually redownloading it?

Yes, I did update the original post with image from Azure DevOps.

The issue of characters getting replaced by ? sounds like either inappropriate collation in the database or a file encoding issue when commiting changes to Git.

And, no, you can't put HTML into email Subject lines and expect it to format things properly (except in really badly behaving web-based mail frontends). If you want to send Unicode (or specifically non-ASCII) characters in Subject lines you probably want to familiarize yourself with RFC 5335 Internationalized Email Headers, but I wouldn't expect SQL Server's .NET-based databasemail.exe utility (which lurks behind sp_send_dbmail) to behave appropriately.

It seems like a encode issue. If you are using UTF-8 for VS2019 and SQL2019?
